# Why is the dialog size so small with this GWT DockLayoutPanel?

Tags: gwt, layout, dialog

I've generated a new Web Application project using GWT 2.0.4.  I replace the onModuleLoad() code with:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    DockLayoutPanel dp = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    dp.addNorth(new Button("north search"), 4);
    dp.addSouth(new Button("Search"), 4);
    dp.addWest(new Button("west"), 4);
    dp.addEast(new Button("east"), 4);

    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(dp);
}
```

That produces what I think is the right thing; four buttons, one on each edge.  But if I try to put that exact same thing into a DialogBox like this:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    DockLayoutPanel dp = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    dp.addNorth(new Button("north search"), 4);
    dp.addSouth(new Button("Search"), 4);
    dp.addWest(new Button("west"), 4);
    dp.addEast(new Button("east"), 4);

    DialogBox dlog = new DialogBox();
    dlog.add(dp);
    dlog.show();

}
```

What I get is a tiny little dialog box squished up in the right hand corner.  The buttons are there but they're only a few pixels wide.

Why?  What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't the dialog box have something very similar to the normal window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RootLayoutPanel is specifically designed to wrap LayoutPanels and takes care of sizing etc. at least to a certain extent. If you want to wrap a LayoutPanel in a normal Widget, you need to set the size of the panel explicitly:

```
DockLayoutPanel dp = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    dp.addNorth(new Button("north search"), 4);
    dp.addSouth(new Button("Search"), 4);
    dp.addWest(new Button("west"), 4);
    dp.addEast(new Button("east"), 4);
    dp.setSize("20em", "20em");

    DialogBox dlog = new DialogBox();
    dlog.add(dp);
    dlog.show();
```

See whether that helps! Good luck!

Comment: Is there any place in the documentation that talks about this sort of thing?  I don't see anything useful in http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html

More specifically, how do you know which of the various widgets need to have an explicit size set, and when?

Comment: Hi James,

take a look here: 

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Design

The documentation is indeed a bit sketchy, but in the "Using a LayoutPanel without RootLayoutPanel" section of the page, the interplay of LayoutPanels and non-LayoutPanels is discussed.