# Using UIBinder to create a Widget to go into a Dialog

Tags: java, gwt, dialog, docklayoutpanel

I found this; which allows me to create the widget in the code:
[Why is the dialog size so small with this GWT DockLayoutPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217253/why-is-the-dialog-size-so-small-with-this-gwt-docklayoutpanel)

but what I want is to use UIBinder.

when I do use it, I get the widget taking up infinite space and hanging below the dialog caption bar.  (obviously not what I want)

for example:

the UIBinder code:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
  <g:north size='4'>
    <g:Label>Header</g:Label>
  </g:north>

  <g:west size='8'>
    <g:Label>Navigation</g:Label>
  </g:west>

  <g:center size="10">
    <g:ScrollPanel>
      <g:Label>Content Area</g:Label>
    </g:ScrollPanel>
  </g:center>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

and if the widget is called WizardPanel;

then the code would be:

```
Dialog mydialog = new Dialog();
mydialog.add(new WizardPanel);
mydialog.show();
```

I've also tried putting the line in:

```
WizardPanel wp = new WizardPanel();
wp.setSize("100em", "100em");
```

before adding it to mydialog, it doesn't make any difference.

I eventually may want to use LayoutPanel; but for now DockLayoutPanel seems sufficient.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a DockLayoutPanel you're not supposed to set the size for the center. The center just takes whatever is left over from the other elements. Other than that I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: i'll try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I think all LayoutPanels need an unbroken chain of LayoutPanels all the way up to the RootLayoutPanel. The Dialog is a "normal" Panel so you must specify the LayoutPanels dimensions explicitly.

See section "**Using a LayoutPanel without RootLayoutPanel**" in the LayoutPanel [Recipes](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Recipes)

Comment: I found that link/site before I wrote this question; it unfortunately wasn't very helpful :(